# Как совместить 2 цикла и будет ли это оптимизировать программу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, оптимизация

Есть такой кусок кода с циклами:

```
inter_mass_n = {item : 0 for i in mass_q for item in range(i[0]-1, i[1])}

for i in mass_q:
    for j in range(i[0]-1, i[1]):
        inter_mass_n[j] += 1
```

Де-факто, программа выполняет лишнюю работу, потому хотелось бы сразу делать `+=1` при создании словаря. Можно ли такое организовать и будет ли такой вариант работать быстрее?

Comment: Что это код делает-то/должен делать?

Comment: Перед циклами - `inter_mass_n = {}`. Тело внутреннего цикла - `inter_mass_n[j] = inter_mass_n.get(j, 0) + 1`.

Comment: @Эникецщик, Вообще весь код нужен для решения олимпиадной задачи. Но если выложить всё решение, то будут стараться решить задачу за меня. А мне интересно можно ли как-то оптимизировать эту часть кода. Чтобы не 2 раза проходиться по массиву, а только один

Comment: mass_q - массив с отрезками, на которых надо складывать числа. Эта часть кода считает сколько раз встречается то или иное число в отрезках. И потом уже идёт подсчёт ответа

Comment: @Эникейщик. С телефона неудобно писать Промахнулся при упоминании)